# Help what is this plant

Tags: identification

Can anyone identify this plant. It is driving me mad now. Any help is much appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure these leaves could be lots of things, but assuming they are as big as they seem to be in your picture (i.e. pretty big), my guess would be ... Hydrangea??

Comment: Yup that was my first impression as well, Lorel!

Answer (score 1):

[hydrangea macrophylla leaves](http://data:image/jpeg;base64,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)  Where are these little plants?  In doors?  Or out of doors?  In 4" pots?  They will need a balanced fertilizer soon.  What are your plans for these plants?  They should be acclimated to the real sun before being planted directly into the garden with extra attention to watering.  They would work in large pots...up potted next into 1 gallon, then 2 gallon, then 5 gallon and possibly 15 gallon.  Do you have winters?  Plants in pots have their roots subjected to too cold and too hot temperatures which could kill the roots and thus the entire plant.

Lorel got the ID is this is correct!